# AWS python lambda deployment package how can i just pull the source or package from source control?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda python deployment package, which means I have to create venv and zip it, and upload it each time I do some change to the python script.
my question is how can configure the AWS lambda to use lambda from source control
that means i what to get this flow:

> function.py --> push to source control -> I manual pull from source
> control from AWS -> AWS using the new script

also, i missing the part of who will create the zip ...

Comment: You need to use some CI/CD Platform like Github Actions, that will check out your code every push, and upload it. all the zip + upload stuff, you can do with the open-source tool https://github.com/serverless/serverless

Comment: this is i have , im talking about he AWS part

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the reference deployment `Serverless CI/CD for the Enterprise on AWS` [here](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/serverless-cicd-for-enterprise/). Note that this deployment uses only only AWS Services and there are a lot of other options besides them. This is a good starting point to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this up quickly and painlessly you can use CodeStar to create a Lambda Python example which is backed by either CodeCommit or Github and it will create the pipelines necessary to deploy your code whenever there is a change for full end to end CICD.

[image: CodeStar Project]